# Chrome extension: How to inject button to an onfocus div(texterea/input) in the page? especially in facebook page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, button, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have been trying to find a way to inject a button when a textarea in the window document got clicked(onfocus) ...for weeks, but I failed to do so.

The function is similar as how Grammarly's extension does.
[Grammarly's extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JVra.png)

The thing is, I want to add a button **nearby or in** the textarea when it is onfocus or keypressed. Then I could return the text value to the extension. **What is the right way to detect the div in the content script?**

the button code is like this:

```
function appendBtn (){
  var btn = document.createElement("INPUT");
  btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  btn.setAttribute("value", "button");
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}

document.onclick = function() {
  appendBtn();
}
```

what I want is to **find the right div** instead of appending the element after body...which it always show at the bottom of the page, especially on facebook page, which I can't even target the input boxes of the comment area..

Please help me with this! I am so desperate right now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [focusin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusin) event (it *bubbles* unlike the `focus` event) in a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) of your extension:

```
var btn = createButton();
document.addEventListener('focusin', onFocusIn);

function onFocusIn(event) {
    var el = event.target;
    if (el.contentEditable ||
        el.matches('input, textarea') && el.type.match(/email|number|search|text|url/))
    {
        appendButton(el);
    }
}

function createButton() {
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.textContent = 'Yay!';
    btn.onclick = function(event) {
        btn.textContent += '!';
    };
    return btn;
}

function appendButton(textElement) {
    textElement.parentElement.insertBefore(btn, textElement.nextElementSibling);
}
```

Comment: it works!! thank you so much!! however, can the button append just once instead of keep duplicating everytime it focused?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! You saved my life! now I could start the next step now! (tears with joy~)

Comment: button is appearing but onclick doesn't work at all.

Comment: @SKYnine, use devtools to set breakpoints and debug the code. Note, I won't be providing support for an old answer in comments so you may want to post a new question instead.

Comment: @wOxxOm just did : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628101/use-extension-to-add-button-to-text-field-not-clickable