# use extension to add button to text field - not clickable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use a chrome extension to dynamically add a button when focusing on a text field (input or text area). the idea would be to click on the button to fill the text field with à string on demand.

I found a bit of code to add up the button but the "onclick" doesn't work.
You will see that I have many ways to trigger console log but none works.
I can't find a way to make this work so I ask for some guidance regarding the way to achieve this.

manifest

```
{
"name": "-",
"description": "-",
"version": "0.1",
"permissions": [
    "tabs","<all_urls>"
    ],
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

"content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
        ],
    "js": ["content.js"]
    }
],


"background" : { "scripts": ["background.js"] },

"manifest_version": 2
}
```

content script

```
var btn = createButton();
document.addEventListener('focusin', onFocusIn);


var el;

function onFocusIn(event) {
    el = event.target;
    if (el.contentEditable ||
        el.matches('input, textarea') && el.type.match(/email|number|search|text|url/))
    {
        appendButton(el);
    }
}

function createButton() {
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.textContent = 'Yay!';
    btn.id = "explicite";
    console.log(btn);

    //not working
    btn.onclick = function(event) {
       btn.textContent += '!';
    };

    //not working
    btn.setAttribute("onClick", "alert('OnClick')");


    return btn;
}

function appendButton(textElement) {
    textElement.parentElement.insertBefore(btn, textElement.nextElementSibling);

    //not working
    document.getElementById("explicite").addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert("HI");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `onFocusIn` code `document.addEventListener('focusin', onFocusIn);`. You are attaching `onFocusIn` on all elements in the documents. Since, a button is also an focusable element `onFocusIn` code executing on that as well.

Simple solution for that is :

```
function onFocusIn(event) {
    el = event.target;
    if(el.type != "button" && el.type != "submit" ) {
        if (el.contentEditable ||
            el.matches('input, textarea') && el.type.match(/email|number|search|text|url/))
        {
            appendButton(el);
        }
    }
}
```

You may want to change the `document.addEventListener('focusin', onFocusIn);` event  code or adjust the binded function.

Hope this is helpful!